# I want to filter data with time range EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I need to filter data. I have a table like this:

```
year  quarter  month  value
----------------------------
2014  2        11     923
...
...
2016  3        7      100
```

I want to get a sum of data between the start and end dates.
For example from year 2014 to 2016.

How is this possible? I could not find anything searching in Google

Answer (score 1):

You can use [LINQ to query data in EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/) like so:

```cs
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    var sum = context.Items
        .Where(x => x.Year >= 2014 && x.Year <= 2016)
        .Sum(x => x.Value);
}
```

`MyDbContext` is your EF Core DB context and `Items` is the name of the DbSet you want to query.